# How to solve below coding exercise

Tags: java

This code was given and was asked to solve it Need help in understanding how this can be solved.

```
    class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should print 7
    System.out.println(stringLength("request")); // this line cannot be changed

    // Should print "request must not be empty"
    System.out.println(stringLength("")); // this line cannot be changed

    // Should print "request is required"
    System.out.println(stringLength(null)); // this line cannot be changed
}

public static Integer stringLength(String request) // this line cannot be changed
{}
```

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It's not possible at least without extra output. Even if your `stringLength` method itseld prints `"request must not be empty"`, it still has to return an integer or null, which would be printed by `main`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher if would have been able to not should have asked here..

Comment: Do what @Michael Butscher proposed, otherwise the question is pointless. And who said you were not allowed to use `system.out.println()` inside the `stringLength(...)` method ?

Comment: whats your thought then @LoneWanderer adding system.out.println inside the stringLength() method would provide you with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The comments say you "should" do a print, but nothing says you cannot print anything else after the print. Nothing even *forces* you to do a print, otherwise it would be a *shall*.

---

To be honest, reading questions about homework like this one makes me unhappy.

To me, the whole thing is useless, ugly, and does not teach anything valuable for future real-world software design and coding. The one thing it teaches is: given poor specifications, do poor work to please the client. *Well ... that is maybe a good lesson to learn ?*

Since you did not give any piece of code of what you tried, nor any hint about what you understood, I took the liberty to propose some kind of a solution that does the required prints.

So here are 3 implementations. I tried to do this in a rough way. Maybe others would find other weird ways to do it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    private static final String REQUEST_MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY = "request must not be empty";
    private static final String REQUEST_IS_REQUIRED = "request is required";
    private static final String REQUEST = "request";
    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
    private static final Map<String, Object> requestMessageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    static {
        // requestMessageMap.put(REQUEST, Integer.valueOf(7));
        // requestMessageMap.put(REQUEST, Integer.valueOf(REQUEST.length()));
        requestMessageMap.put(EMPTY_STRING, REQUEST_MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY);
        requestMessageMap.put(null, REQUEST_IS_REQUIRED);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Should print 7
        System.out.println(stringLength("request")); // this line cannot be changed

        // Should print "request must not be empty"
        System.out.println(stringLength("")); // this line cannot be changed

        // Should print "request is required"
        System.out.println(stringLength(null)); // this line cannot be changed
    }

    public static Integer stringLength(String request) // this line cannot be changed
    {
        return sillyMethod4(request);
    }

    private static Integer sillyMethod1(String request) {
        Integer returnValue = -1;
        if (request == null) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            System.err.println(REQUEST_IS_REQUIRED);
        } else if (request.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            System.err.println(REQUEST_MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY);
        } else if (request.equals(REQUEST)) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            returnValue = 7;
        } else {
            // my best guess about what we should really do
            returnValue = request.length();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static Integer lessSillyMethod2(String request) {
        Integer returnValue = -1;
        if (request == null) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            System.err.println(REQUEST_IS_REQUIRED);
        } else if (request.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            System.err.println(REQUEST_MUST_NOT_BE_EMPTY);
        } else {
            // my best guess about what we should really do
            returnValue = request.length();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static Integer sillyMethod3(String request) {
        Integer returnValue = -1;
        if (request == null) {
            // do exactly what specification required
            // (completly pointeless)
            System.err.println("request is required: ");
        } else {
            switch (request) {
            case EMPTY_STRING:
                // do exactly what specification required
                // (completly pointeless)
                System.err.println("request must not be empty: ");
                break;
            case REQUEST:
                // do exactly what specification required
                // (completly pointeless)
                returnValue = 7; //
                break;
            default:
                // my best guess about what we should really do
                returnValue = request.length();
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static Integer sillyMethod4(String request) {
        Integer returnValue = -1;
        if (requestMessageMap.containsKey(request)) {
            System.err.println(requestMessageMap.get(request));
        } else {
            returnValue = request.length();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
7
request must not be empty
request is required
-1
-1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @LoneWandere its a stright forward approach that you mentioned in your comment above but its still printing extra -1 which i did avoid as this was asked to me in a interview and i didnt wanted to print the extra -1. The way i thought of doing it was retunring the int values based on the string input parameter length or otherwise -1 .but to override the ** system.out.println()** method so that based on int value returned it can print the required value or string.

Answer (score -3):

The method stringLengt() should return "7" when you pass it the string "request", a different value when you pass it an empty string and another different value, when you pass null. Maybe you should take a look on control structures, especially selections. Also your stringLength method needs to return values of type String.

Comment: what specifically you mean here to look at especially selections.. i understand that but how will you do the logic of Printing once the length and other cases  the messages without changing the lines mentioned.  Please go through the comments carefully first then reply.

Comment: Your method needs to return a value based on the input you pass it. You could achieve that with a case structure, a selection.

Comment: And will that fulfill the value that i need to print..passing it from case is not unknown but it will then print the same returned values whereas if we have to print two different strings in blank and null case.